# C ints and chars. Strange behavior

Tags: c

I am learning C language and I am facing a problem I don't seem to be able to resolve on my own.
I have a simple loop where I add up ascii values of all characters in each word.

```
    char char_array[100];
    int lexicographical_values[20];
    int i, j = 0;
    for( i = 0; i <strlen(char_array); i++) {
          if(char_array[i] == ' ') 
              j++;
          lexicographical_values[j] += (int)char_array[i];   
    }
```

Then, if I output the lexicographical_values array in a loop

```
  printf("%d word is: %d \n", i, lexicographical_values[i]);
```

I get correct figures for each word (ex: dd = 200 and so on)

But if I actually look at each element's value in the array, I get big numbers  that are far from being correct.

The question is, how do I get correct values and how does printf obtain the correct values?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of these "big numbers"?

Comment: what exactly are you seeing and what do you expect?

Comment: The elements in which array is wrong? How are you looking at them? How are you getting the right answer if the numbers are wrong?

Also, are you meant to be adding the value for space too?

Comment: The cast from `char` to `int` is unnecessary (just like you didn't use one when comparing to `' '`, which is an `int` constant).

Comment: You don't need the cast to `(int)` since `char` type is integral and there will be implicit conversion, but apart from using uninitialized memory, the biggest problem is your assumption that a `char`'s value represents its ASCII value.  This need not be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized the lexicographical_values array. You can initialize it by doing:

```
int lexicographical_values[20] = {};
```

Every time you see *big numbers* in the output, check for uninitialized variables.

Comment: Especially large negative numbers you weren't expecting

Comment: Since the total for a word should never be a negative value perhaps lexicographical_values should be an array of unsigned int's rather than ints

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked! I was wondering about array initialisation but didn't believe that a loop would be an elegant solution.

Comment: Nitpick note: the empty braces will work in C++, but for C (unless the compiler is using a language extension) there needs to be at least one const for the 1st item (the remainder will be zero-initialized), so this needs to be `int lexicographical_values[20] = {0};`

Answer (score 2):

You're starting with uninitialized memory.

```
man memset
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the char_array with anything, so most likely it has garbage (depends on compiler options and platforms) so, you do a `strlen(char_array)` and at this point we're not sure what we're going to get out of it. If you initialize it with 0s (like: `char char_array[100] = {0};` then `strlen` will return 0 and you'll never enter the loop.

Maybe you're looking for `sizeof()` here?

Oh, yes, forgot to mention that you need to initialize the second array also as was already pointed out.